# Draw the Khan Academy logo using Python turtle graphics

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I am trying to draw the Khan Academy logo using turtle graphics in Python but I got stuck when trying to draw the blossoms. Should I do that using a function and how is that done exactly? Or should I draw 2 half circles to achieve it?

I have already started trying with half circles but cannot figure it out.

```
# circle
t.color("white")
t.up()
t.goto(-25,0)
t.down()
t.begin_fill()
t.circle(60)
t.end_fill()

# blossom
t.up()
t.goto(-25,-150)
t.down()
t.rt(45)
```

The output should be similar to the Khan Academy logo.

Answer (score 1):

> I have already started trying with half circles but still can not
>   figure it out.

You drew a circle, but your half circle attempts are missing in your code above.  You should provide as much of your attempts as possible.

This logo can be drawn using just turtle's `circle()` method.  But, you need to fully understand all three arguments:

```
circle(radius, extent=None, steps=None)
```

In particular, what it means to use a negative `radius`.  (Learning what a negative `extent` does wouldn't hurt either.)

I was able to simply eyeball the logo to come up with:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

RADIUS = 100

screen = Screen()
screen.colormode(255)

turtle = Turtle(visible=False)
turtle.speed('fastest')  # because I have no patience
turtle.penup()  # we'll use fill instead of lines
turtle.color(20, 191, 150)  # greenish color

turtle.sety(-RADIUS)  # center hexagon
turtle.begin_fill()
turtle.circle(RADIUS, steps=6)  # draw hexagon
turtle.end_fill()

turtle.color('white')  # interior color
turtle.sety(2 * RADIUS / 11)  # position circle (head)
turtle.begin_fill()
turtle.circle(2 * RADIUS / 9)  # draw circle (head)
turtle.end_fill()

turtle.forward(5 * RADIUS / 8)
turtle.right(85)

turtle.begin_fill()
turtle.circle(-13 * RADIUS / 20, 190)
turtle.right(85)
turtle.circle(-13 * RADIUS / 20, 90)
turtle.left(180)
turtle.circle(-13 * RADIUS / 20, 90)
turtle.end_fill()

screen.exitonclick()
```

[image]

What I recommend you do is review the [Wikipedia entry for Hexagon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexagon) and figure out all the useful interior points of a hexagon that might help you design a solution based on geometry.  You know it can be done, now do it well.